# Is it possible to pass a variable's value as the event label in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I have multiple points on a map that, when clicked, display a popup with information on the points. One of attributes is called `pointNo`.

I'd like to pass the value of `pointNo` for each point as an event label.

example:
ga('send','event','Map','click', pointNo);

Doesn't seem to work though. Anyone know if it's possible? If not, does anyone know why it's not?

Is my only option to use a Custom Dimension?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Would this (using custom variables) work? 

`ga('send','event','map','click', {'dimension1': dimensionValue});`

Comment: Yes, it is possible (you can pass any string to a label) and you do not need a custom dimension. There is however not enough information in the post to debug this. Install the Google Analytics Debugger extension in Chrome (or Google Tag Assistant) to check if the value for pointNo is actually set in the request when it is sent to Google.